# How do I range a slice that's contained inside a slice of structs in a template?

Tags: go

I am trying to range over a couple of nested slices inside a template but get an error:

```
panic: template: abc:3: unexpected <range> in range

goroutine 1 [running]:
text/template.Must(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/text/template/helper.go:23
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox748332064/main.go:38 +0x560
```

I've tried searching the docs but can't seem to figure out a workaround to being able to execute the code, even though is seems really simple.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Person struct {
    name     string
    children []string
}

func main() {
    p := []*Person{
      {
        name:     "Susy",
        children: []string{"Bob", "Herman", "Sherman"},
      },
      {
        name:     "Norman",
        children: []string{"Rachel", "Ross", "Chandler"},
      },
    }

    str := `
      {{$people := .}}
      {{range $i, $pp := range $people}}
        {{$children := $pp.children}}
        Name: {{$pp.name}}
        Children:
          {{range $j, $c := $children}}
          Child {{$j}}: {{$c}}
          {{end}}                   
      {{end}}
    `

    t := template.Must(template.New("abc").Parse(str))
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, p)
    if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
    }

}
```

[my playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5JXZmwPAllC)

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, you've got an extra `range` here: `range $i, $pp := range $people`. Looks like you may be conflating the template range syntax with the Go range syntax and putting `range` on both sides of the assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this syntax for range:

```
  {{range $i, $pp := $people}}
    {{$children := $pp.Children}}
    Name: {{$pp.Name}}
    Children:
      {{range $j, $c := $children}}
      Child {{$j}}: {{$c}}
      {{end}}                   
  {{end}}
```

Also, [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the struct fields so the fields can be used by the template.  Use those exported names in the template.

[Run it in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8W7XMSmfUMa)